# Any way to set editActions on a ListView with dataCollection?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have a ListView that's hooked to a dataCollection, is it possible to add editActions?

Can't seem to find a way to add these to my ItemTemplate or ListItem.

Here's my (shortened) view:

```
<ListView id="listViewSpots" defaultItemTemplate="history">
    <Templates>
        <ItemTemplate name="history" id="itemTemplateHistory" canEdit="true">
            <Label bindId="serie" class="serie" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <ListSection id="listSectionSpots" dataCollection="spot" dataFilter="listFilter">
        <ListItem itemId="{id}" serie:text="{serie}" searchableText="{serie}" />
    </ListSection>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: added some code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom actions like this:

```
"ListItem[platform=ios]":{
accessoryType: Titanium.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_DISCLOSURE,
editActions: [{ title: "Add",
                style: Ti.UI.iOS.ROW_ACTION_STYLE_DEFAULT },
                { title: "Archive",
                style: Ti.UI.iOS.ROW_ACTION_STYLE_DEFAULT },]
}
```

Comment: Doh, this is the most straightforward answer. Had to put it on the ItemTemplate though. You can even put actions on a specific template this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Editable and EditActions are just regular properties of a ListItem and can be added as such. Through a transform function (`dataTransform`) you can make this customizable as well

```
<ListView id="listViewSpots" defaultItemTemplate="history">
    <Templates>
        <ItemTemplate name="history" id="itemTemplateHistory" canEdit="true">
            <Label bindId="serie" class="serie" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <ListSection id="listSectionSpots" dataCollection="spot" dataFilter="listFilter">
        <ListItem 
          itemId="{id}" 
          serie:text="{serie}" 
          searchableText="{serie}" 
          editable="{editable}"
          editActions="{editActions}"
       />
    </ListSection>
</ListView>
```

This way you can still configure it per ListItem

Comment: Already tried it this way, gives me a native xcode/objective-c error about trying to parse an Array as a String.

Comment: then something problably is wrong in the code, because this is exactly  how I have it set up ;)

Comment: Must be :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: had the same error as Rick, but doing it in .tss worked for me

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible.

Can you specify your issue ?

Can you enable slide action?
Do you wanna know how to handle click event?

Maybe this can help you:
"ItemTemplate[platform=ios]":{
canEdit: true
}

Comment: I added some code, i want to add custom editActions to the listitems instead of the default "Delete".